# How to activate a Schengen visa issued by an embassy within Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a Vietnamese national and have been studying in Finland for the past 3 years. I have a student residence permit, which is renewed every year.

This year, I am going on an exchange in Lithuania for a year. Because of that, I do not have any grounds for a Finnish student residence permit.

The Lithuanian embassy in Finland issued me a national Type D visa. I have arrived in lithuania but there was no border control between Lithuania and Finland.

Will my visa still be valid? I wish to travel outside Schengen (to Belarus) and come back. Is this allowed? Belarusian authorities want to see a Schengen visa that has been used at least once. What does it mean?

Comment: I guess you should ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange, not here.

Comment: Your Lithuanian visum [seems](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com) to be a Schengen visum, and since you are in Lithuania you are using it. If the Belarus ppl wants to see a stamp you could get one from the Lithuanian border ppl, perhaps. It should say one the Visum in your passport if it is valid for Schengen area or only Lithuania.

Comment: The thing is there aren't any entry stamp because I entered Schengen area through Finland when my old Finnish residence permit are still in activated. But now it is expired, and I entered lithuania from finland so i have no idea if it is allowed to be use.